# How I can generated pre-signed url for different file versions of AWS S3 objects in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

In my AWS S3 bucket, I have the same file with different versions. How can I generate a pre-signed URL for each version of the same file?
I am using **NodeJS AWS SDK**.

[image]

Comment: Which AWS SDK are you using? Python, Java, Javascript, or some other?

Comment: @abdullahkhawer, I am using node js

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code to get the pre-signed URL for a specific version of an object in AWS S3 Bucket using NodeJS AWS SDK:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const AWS_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 'v4';

const s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: <aws-access-key>,
  secretAccessKey: <aws-secret-access-key>,
  region: <aws-region>,
  signatureVersion: AWS_SIGNATURE_VERSION
});

const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: <aws-s3-bucket-name>,
    Key: <aws-s3-object-key>,
    VersionId: <aws-s3-object-version-id>
    Expires: <url-expiry-time-in-seconds>
})

console.log(url)
```

Note: Don't forget to replace the placeholders (<...>) with actual values to make it work.